# ASP .Net Route to ignore pages folder

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes, iis-8

My Web Forms app has all aspx files in a root "pages" folder. So, when I try to access them, obviously the url will be http://mysite/pages/default.aspx. Is there a way (other than a rewrite rule in web.config) with routes to ignore the "pages" folder and have all my urls like http://mysite/default.aspx?

Cheers

Comment: Did you do any basic research for "ASP.NET Web Forms routing"?  There's a lot of great information out there about it, you can remove that folder name and remove the file extension.

Comment: Yap, this is stupid as I've found lots and lots of information regardind other cases (including friendly urls, etc.). I'm still researching, but with this particular I'm having a hard time finding out a solution

Comment: If you put the exact search terms in that I mentioned into a mainstream search engine  you will find great results.